# $V$ is isomorphic to $V^{\ast\ast}$, the double dual space of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that for any vector space $V$ the map sending $v$ in $V$ to (evaluation at $v$) $E_v$ in $V^{**}$  such that $E_v(\phi) = \phi(v)$ for $\phi$ in $V^*$ , is injective. Derive from this that if $\dim V < \infty$, its double dual $V^{**}$  is naturally isomorphic to $V$.

Here $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$.

Answer (score 16):

Denote the evaluation map at $v$ by $\bar{v}$. Then the map $\tau v=\bar{v}$ from $V\to V^{\ast\ast}$ is indeed an injective linear transformation. Linearity is easy. Now suppose $v\in\ker(\tau)$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\tau v=0 &\implies \bar{v}=0\\
&\implies \bar{v}(f)=0\quad\forall f\in V^\ast\\
&\implies f(v)=0\quad\forall f\in V^\ast\\
&\implies v=0
\end{align*}
$$
since $v\in V$ is zero iff $f(v)=0$ for all linear functionals on $V$. Thus $\ker(\tau)=\{0\}$, so $\tau$ is injective.

To see it is an isomorphism, it is useful to recall the fact that
$$
\dim(V)\leq\dim(V^\ast)
$$
with equality holding iff $V$ is finite dimensional, so applying this twice you find
$$
\dim(V)=\dim(V^\ast)=\dim(V^{\ast\ast})
$$ 
so $\tau$ is an injective transformation between vector spaces of equal dimension, hence and isomorphism by rank-nullity.

Comment: Fair enough, deleted

Comment: How/why do things break down for the finite-dimensional case?

Comment: @MSIS If you mean why equality fails in the infinite dimensional case, lots of good information is in this note by Keith Conrad https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/dualspaceinfinite.pdf

Answer (score 8):

Without knowing where you are stuck, it is difficult to give informative answers. I'll give two hints:

- If a vector space homomorphism between vector spaces of the same finite dimension is injective, then it is also $---$?
- To show a map between vector spaces in injective, show that if $v$ maps to zero, it implies $v$ zero too.

Comment: In your question *If a vector space homomorphism between finite-dimensional vector spaces is injective, then it is also −−−?* you have left out the condition that they have the same dimension.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Thanks for the remark. I was a bit too quick.