# Injection from dual space into double dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces, canonical-transformation

I know for a vector space $V$ over the real or complex numbers, there exists a canonical embedding into its double dual $V^{**}$, and if $V$ is given an inner product, then there is a canonical embedding from $V$ into $V^*$.

However, I was not sure if there is any canonical embedding from $V^*$ into $V^{**}$ that is compatible with the above emebeddings, i.e. if
$$\sigma:V \rightarrow V^{**}, \sigma(v)(f)=f(v)$$
$$\iota:V \rightarrow V^*, \iota(v)(w)=\langle w,v \rangle$$
are injective linear map.

So my question is: Is there a canonical (does not depend on basis) injective linear map  $\mu: V^* \rightarrow V^{**}$ such that
$$\sigma = \mu \circ \iota$$
I try to build an inner product on $V^*$ based on the inner product on $V$ but to no avail.

Comment: Your whole question is about definitions. What is the definition of independent of basis ? I think the answer is no so you need a way of disproving the statement. There is a categorical definition, but here is a second question, which maps $f:V\to W$ for inner product spaces do you consider ? You can only take the orthogonal to have the imbedding $i$ be canonical. Course if your on the category of finite spaces then the answer is yes, cause all maps are isomorphisms.

Comment: About canonical map, I mean the categorical definition (the one with natural transformation), though for $\iota: V \rightarrow V^*$ is not technically so. I probably not get what you mean in the later half, but I look for general linear map (not just specific kind of map between inner product space), and I had thought that $\mu$ must be induced from some inner product structure on $V^*$ just like $\iota$ (I probably need to remove "canonical" from the maps that use inner product)

Comment: related [$V$ is isomorphic to $V^{\ast\ast}$, the double dual space of $V$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292353/v-is-isomorphic-to-v-ast-ast-the-double-dual-space-of-v)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $V$ is finite dimensional, $\iota$ is an isomorphism, so you can just take $\mu=\sigma\circ \iota^{-1}$.  In general, however, no such canonical map $\mu$ exists.

As evidence for this, consider the case that $V=\mathbb{R}^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$ with the usual dot product as the inner product. Then $V^*$ can naturally be identified with $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, and the image of $\iota$ is the subspace $\mathbb{R}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ of sequences of finite support.  Note now that it is consistent with ZF that the dual of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is just $\mathbb{R}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$.  In that case, there cannot exist any linear injection $V^*\to V^{**}$ at all, essentially since $V^{**}$ is countable-dimensional and $V^*$ is not (though it takes a bit of work to make this argument rigorous in the absence of choice).  So, it is not possible to prove that such a map $\mu$ exists without using the axiom of choice.

Comment: Sorry for taking long enough to accept your answer because I'm getting stuck at why $\{ s \in \mathbb{R}^B: \mu(s) \text{ vanishes on } \mathbb{R}^{\oplus B} \}$ is a complement subspace to $\mathbb{R}^{\oplus B}$. Anyway, thank you for great answer.

Comment: Hmmm, revisiting this now, it seems that claim was wrong.  I've replaced the argument with a different one (which has a somewhat weaker conclusion).